# Common subscribe for multiple observables with observable to be edited inside the callback

Tags: knockout.js

I have a requirement where I have 2 or more input fields which have to accept a number. Both the values are set as knockout observables (number_one and number_two) in the corresponding js file and need to be converted to decimal type if an integer is provided. I can achieve this by writing separate subscribe for each of the observables, however the callback code is same and hence this does not seem to be an efficient way.

```
self.number_one = ko.observable();
self.number_two = ko.observable();

self.number_one.subscribe(function(number_one){
    number_one = Number(number_one).toFixed(2);
    self.number_one(number_one);
})

self.number_two.subscribe(function(number_two){
    number_two = Number(number_two).toFixed(2);
    self.number_two(number_two);
})
```

I found a way to write a common subscribe for both the observables on an internet forum, however this does not provide a way to change the observable with which the subscribe is called, which is the scenario in my case.

Below is the method I found on internet which doesn't help in my case as the callback only logs the value passed in console but does not provide a way to change the observable it is called with.

```
var callback = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};
          
function subscribeMany(callback, observables) {
    for (var i = 0; i < observables.length; i++) {
        observables[i].subscribe(callback);
    }
}
          
subscribeMany(callback, [self.number_one, self.number_two]);
```

Could someone please help me with this case? I am new to Knockout JS.

Answer (score 0):

In your code replace

```
var callback = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
};
```

with

```
    var callback = function(value) {
      return Number(value).toFixed(2);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't help. Still I get the observable as an integer instead of changing it into a decimal number.

Comment: @codecrazy46 I have updated my answer by making little changes in the code. Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Extending Observables page of the Knockout documentation. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html

I think the below example (which is a copy of the example **"Live Example 1: Forcing input to be numeric"** from the documentation) is what you might be looking for.

```js
ko.extenders.numeric = function(target, precision) {
    //create a writable computed observable to intercept writes to our observable
    var result = ko.pureComputed({
        read: target,  //always return the original observables value
        write: function(newValue) {
            var current = target(),
                roundingMultiplier = Math.pow(10, precision),
                newValueAsNum = isNaN(newValue) ? 0 : +newValue,
                valueToWrite = Math.round(newValueAsNum * roundingMultiplier) / roundingMultiplier;
 
            //only write if it changed
            if (valueToWrite !== current) {
                target(valueToWrite);
            } else {
                //if the rounded value is the same, but a different value was written, force a notification for the current field
                if (newValue !== current) {
                    target.notifySubscribers(valueToWrite);
                }
            }
        }
    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
 
    //initialize with current value to make sure it is rounded appropriately
    result(target());
 
    //return the new computed observable
    return result;
};
 
function AppViewModel(one, two) {
    this.myNumberOne = ko.observable(one).extend({ numeric: 0 });
    this.myNumberTwo = ko.observable(two).extend({ numeric: 2 });
}
 
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(221.2234, 123.4525));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberOne" /> (round to whole number)</p>
<p><input data-bind="value: myNumberTwo" /> (round to two decimals)</p>
```